# i got an error.Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).when i give listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I get the following error:

`"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" .`

when attempting to set the permissions of a list item with the following code:

```
 if (!listitem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
 { 
    listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);//I got an error here 
 }
```

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 3):

What is calling `BreakRoleInheritance`? Let's say it is an Event Receiver, but whatever it is, you need to make sure that the user has adequate permissions. Just because a user can add or update items in a list, doesn't mean that user has rights to call `BreakRoleInheritance`. For that, the user must have Manage Permissions rights.

To ensure the proper permissions, it is safest to call `BreakRoleInheritance` in the context of the site collection system account:

```
if (!listitem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
{ 
    Guid siteId = listitem.Web.Site.ID; 
    Guid webId = listitem.Web.ID;
    Guid listId = listitem.ParentList.ID;
    int itemId = listitem.ID;
    SPUserToken token = listitem.Web.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId, token))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists[listId];
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
        }
    }
}
```

A couple other things to check:

1. If you are using elevated privileges, set [allow unsafe updates to true](http://umakanthn.blogspot.com/2007/07/breakroleinheritance-throws-access-is.html).
2. If versioning is enabled, be sure the item is [checked in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868056/27482).